# xpath parent attribute of selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Syntax of the xml document:

```
<x name="GET-THIS">
  <y>
    <z>Z</z> 
    <z>Z__2</z>
    <z>Z__3</z>   
  </y>
</x>
```

I'm able to get all z elements using:

```
xpath("//z")
```

But after that I got stuck, I'm not sure what to do next. I don't really understand the syntax of the `..` parent method

So, how do I get the attribute of the parent of the parent of the element?

Comment: Try out `xpath("//x[//z]/@name")`. It'll select `x` elements which have `z` elements as descendants and then get its `name` attribute.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Add it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of traversing back to the parent, just find the right parent to begin with:

- `//x` will select all `x` elements.
- `//x[//z]` will select all `x` elements which have `z` elements as descendants.
- `//x[//z]/@name` will get the `name` attribute of each of those elements.

Answer (score 4):

You already have a good accepted answer, but here are some other helpful expressions:

- `//z/ancestor::x/@name` - Find `<z>` elements anywhere, then find all the ancestor `<x>` elements, and then the `name="…"` attributes of them.
- `//z/../../@name` - Find the `<z>` elements, and then find the parent node(s) of those, and then the parent node(s) of those, and then the `name` attribute(s) of the final set.

  - This is the same as: `//z/parent::*/parent::*/@name`, where the `*` means "an element with any name".
- The `//` is useful, but inefficient. If you know that the hierarchy is `x/y/z`, then it is more efficient to do something like `//x[y/z]/@name`

Comment: For me, it was the `*` that helped... I needed `parent::*/@id` to work... I tried `parent::@id` and `parent::/@id` and neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a reputation, so I cannot add comment to accepted answer by Blender. But his answer will not work in general.
Correct version is

```
//x[.//z]/@name
```

Explanation is simple - when you use filter like `[//z]` it will search for 'z' in global context, i.e. it returns *true* if xml contains at least one node *z* anywhere in xml. For example, it will select both names from xml below:

```
<root>
  <x name="NOT-THIS">
  </x>
  <x name="GET-THIS">
     <y>
        <z>Z</z> 
        <z>Z__2</z>
        <z>Z__3</z>   
     </y>
  </x>
</root>
```

Filter `[.//z]` use context of current node (.) which is `x`and return only 2nd name.