# How to get parents and grand parents tags given specific attribute in XML in python?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xpath

I have an xml with a structure like this one:

```
<cat>
  <foo>
    <fooID>1</fooID>
    <fooName>One</fooName>
    <bar>
      <barID>a</barID>
      <barName>small_a</barName>
      <barClass>
        <baz>
          <qux>
            <corge>
              <corgeName>...</corgeName>
              <corgeType>
                <corgeReport>
                  <corgeReportRes Reference="x" Channel="High">
                    <Pos>1</Pos>
                  </corgeReportRes>
                </corgeReport>
              </corgeType>
            </corge>
          </qux>
        </baz>
      </barClass>
    </bar>
    <bar>
      <barID>b</barID>
      <barName>small_b</barName>
      <barClass>
        <baz>
          <qux>
            <corge>
              <corgeName>...</corgeName>
              <corgeType>
                <corgeReport>
                  <corgeReportRes Reference="y" Channel="High">
                    <Pos>1</Pos>
                  </corgeReportRes>
                </corgeReport>
              </corgeType>
            </corge>
          </qux>
        </baz>
      </barClass>
    </bar>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <fooID>2</fooID>
    <fooName>Two</fooName>
    <bar>
      <barID>c</barID>
      <barName>small_c</barName>
      <barClass>
        <baz>
          <qux>
            <corge>
              <corgeName>...</corgeName>
              <corgeType>
                <corgeReport>
                  <corgeReportRes Reference="z" Channel="High">
                    <Pos>1</Pos>
                  </corgeReportRes>
                </corgeReport>
              </corgeType>
            </corge>
          </qux>
        </baz>
      </barClass>
    </bar>
  </foo>
</cat>
```

And, I would like to obtain the values of specific parent/grand parent/grand grand parent tags that have a node with attribute `Channel="High"`. I would like to obtain only fooID value, fooName value, barID value, barName value.

I have the following code in Python 3:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xmlET

root = xmlET.parse('file.xml').getroot()
test = root.findall(".//*[@Channel='High']")
```

Which is actually giving me a list of elements that match, however, I still need the information of the specific parents/grand parents/grand grand parents.

How could I do that?

```
fooID | fooName | barID | barName
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1     |     One |     a | small_a  <-- This is the information I'm interested
1     |     One |     b | small_b  <-- Also this
2     |     Two |     c | small_c  <-- And this
```

Edit: `fooID` and `fooName` nodes are siblings of the grand-grand-parent `bar`, the one that contains the `Channel="High"`. It's almost the same case for `barID` and `barName`, they are siblings of the grand-parent `barClass`, the one that contains the `Channel="High"`. Also, what I want to obtain is the values `1`, `One`, `a` and `small_a`, not filtering by it, since there will be multiple foo blocks.

Comment: have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16954547/3513695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are probably looking for something like this (using [python](/questions/tagged/python)):

```
from lxml import etree
foos = """[your xml above]"""
items = []
for entry in doc.xpath('//foo[.//corgeReportRes[@Channel="High"]]'):
    items.append(entry.xpath('./fooID/text()')[0])
    items.append(entry.xpath('./fooName/text()')[0])
    items.append(entry.xpath('./bar/barID/text()')[0])
    items.append(entry.xpath('./bar/barName/text()')[0])
print('fooID | fooName | barID | barName')
print('  |  '.join(items))
```

Output:

```
fooID | fooName | barID | barName
1  |  One  |  a  |  small_a
```